# Python's subprocess.call("touch", ..) is not running sucessfully from PHP

Tags: php, python, apache2

I am new to the idea of running something such as a Python script on a server using PHP. I have some scripts running successfully using simple PHP code such as the following:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
script output:<br>
<?php 
$command = escapeshellcmd('/path/user/public_html/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

A Python script that runs successfully is something such as the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

A Python script that does not run successfully is something such as the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import call
call(["touch", "/path/user/public_html/test.txt"])
```

I do not understand why the first one works and the second one doesn't. What is going on here?

The server is running Scientific Linux 5 and I have user-level, not root-level, control of the server.

Comment: Run the second Python program directly. What happens? Trivially: if PHP doesn't capture the stdout in one case, then there is no appropriate stdout stream generated. So throw away the assertion that PHP/Apache are a culprit (excepting that they change the environment in which Python is running) and focus *only* on the Python - and in particular, the difference between the command executed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. When I run the second Python program directly (```python test.py``` or ```./test.py```), it runs successfully and the file ```test.txt``` is created.

Comment: So go back to "excepting that they change the environment in which Python is running". Two likely culprits are 1. permissions (eg. no write on the directory) or; 2. current working directory is unexpected.

Comment: Thanks again for your ideas. I think the specified directory is fine (it is the full path), so it may be that the permissions are not usable by Apache2 for some reason. I have created a new directory, specified it in the program and run ```chmod 777``` on it but the file ```test.txt``` still is not getting created in it. I'm not sure what to do next.